# Excel VBA Weird Issue

Tags: excel, vba, csv

Excel Script deletes empty records(blank lines(,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,)) from a directory of files and saves as csv.  On a few random files out of 80 it deletes all rows except the header row.  Any ideas.  Debug led me to code below, last line is where removal happens, but looks as though it definitely should work for all files and def does for most.

No merged columns exist and no weird formatting.

Edited to show Full Script: (Warning: Very Ugly at the moment(Debugging and Circumstances))

```
Sub SaveToCSVs()
Dim fDir As String
Dim wB As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fPath As String
Dim sPath As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim cellMid As Range
Dim MiddleName As String
Dim MiddleNameColumn As ListColumn
Dim d As Double
Dim C As Range

Dim LR As Long, i As Long

fPath = "C:\PPEAug\Rosters EMP ID\"
sPath = "C:\PPEAug\Rosters EMP ID\Converted\"
fDir = Dir(fPath)

Do While (fDir <> "")

If Right(fDir, 4) = ".xls" Or Right(fDir, 5) = ".xlsx" Then

On Error Resume Next
    Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fDir)
    Set ws = wB.ActiveSheet
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = False
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each ws In wB.Sheets


With Range("A:Z")
    .Value2 = Evaluate("INDEX(Trim(" & .Address(0, 0) & "),,)")
    End With

Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
    Range("D2:D5000").Select

Dim rg As Range
    For Each rg In Selection
    rg.NumberFormat = "@"
    If Len(rg.Value) < 12 And Len(rg.Value) > 0 Then
    rg.Value = WorksheetFunction.Rept("0", 12 - Len(rg.Value)) & rg.Value
End If
Next

Columns("E:E").Select
    Set rg = Selection
    rg.NumberFormat = "000-00-0000"

Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("H1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove



        Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="-JR", Replacement:=" JR", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="-SR", Replacement:=" SR", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="-II", Replacement:=" II", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="-III", Replacement:=" III", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="-IV", Replacement:=" IV", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:=", ", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
    Dim rCell As Range, strChar As String
    strChar = "-"

Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="'", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "LAST NAME"

Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("G1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

For Each cell In Range("$A$1:" & Range("$A$1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Address)
    If Len(cell) > 0 Then cell = UCase(cell)
Next cell
Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "AFFILIATE"
Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PPE"
Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "DUES AMT"
Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "EMP ID"
Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SSN"
Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "DOB"
Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "LAST NAME"
Range("H1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NAME SUFFIX"
Range("I1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PlaceHolder"
Range("J1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "FIRST NAME"
Range("K1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MIDDLE NAME"
Range("L1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SECOND MIDDLE"
Range("M1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ADDRESS 1"
Range("N1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ADDRESS 2"
Range("O1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "CITY"
Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "STATE"
Range("Q1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ZIP"
Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="L", Replacement:="l", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="A", Replacement:="a", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.Replace What:="B", Replacement:="b", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "AFFIlIATE"



Columns("G:G").Select
    For Each C In Selection
    If Right(C.Value, 1) = "-" Then
    C.Value = Left(C.Value, Len(C.Value) - 1)
End If
Next C
Columns("G:G").Select
    For Each C In Selection
    If Right(C.Value, 1) = "-" Then
    C.Value = Left(C.Value, Len(C.Value) - 1)
End If
Next C
Columns("H:H").Select
    For Each C In Selection
    If Right(C.Value, 1) = "-" Then
    C.Value = Left(C.Value, Len(C.Value) - 1)
End If
Next C
Columns("H:H").Select
    For Each C In Selection
    If Right(C.Value, 1) = "-" Then
    C.Value = Left(C.Value, Len(C.Value) - 1)
End If
Next C
Columns("J:J").Select
    For Each C In Selection
    If Right(C.Value, 1) = "-" Then
    C.Value = Left(C.Value, Len(C.Value) - 1)
End If
Next C
Columns("J:J").Select
    For Each C In Selection
    If Right(C.Value, 1) = "-" Then
    C.Value = Left(C.Value, Len(C.Value) - 1)
End If
Next C
Columns("K:K").Select
    For Each C In Selection
    If Right(C.Value, 1) = "-" Then
    C.Value = Left(C.Value, Len(C.Value) - 1)
End If
Next C
Columns("K:K").Select
    For Each C In Selection
    If Right(C.Value, 1) = "-" Then
    C.Value = Left(C.Value, Len(C.Value) - 1)
End If
Next C

Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'DataLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'SheetLastRow = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
'ws.Rows(DataLastRow + 1 & ":" & SheetLastRow).Delete

NameOfWorkbook = Left(wB.Name, (InStrRev(wB.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
ws.SaveAs sPath & NameOfWorkbook & ".csv", xlCSV
Next ws
wB.Close False
Set wB = Nothing

    End If

    fDir = Dir
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop
MsgBox "PPE Roster Conversion Completed." 
End Sub
```

Comment: it must be because column A, which you use to determine `DataLastRow` doesn't have any values in it

Comment: Also based on the way you're doing this, you cant just remove the `With ...` and `End With`, because they're not being used

Comment: Yeah the With is going, there was other stuff.  Column A Does in fact have data.  That's why its so weird.

Comment: What's odd to me is that you are getting values from whatever sheet is being referenced by `ws`, but you are deleting rows in the active sheet. Those aren't necessarily the same thing.

Comment: This script has gone through a million changes over the course of a month.  It a little messy right now.  Removed the ActiveSheet and With statements.  Still deletes all data except headers.  To reiterate, Column A does have data in it.  So confusing.  Works for 73 out of 80 files.  :(  Column A is one of the columns guaranteed to always have data in it from the file provider which is why I use that one.  I'd post the file but it has sensitive info

Comment: @StoneGiant good point. Wouldn’t be the first time I saw `set ws = Activesheet`, though

Comment: To clarify, all files only contain one sheet as well, so ActiveSheet would always have been the correct sheet unless I'm crazy lol

Comment: It depends on how you’re iterating through all the workbooks but idk

Comment: Yeah this one for the books, holy moly

Comment: Can you let us see the entire method?

Comment: Edited to show full script.  Its super ugly....not my fault  LOL  Also the files come from 67 different sources so we have to account for everything before upload to MySQL database

Comment: Don't worry about the messy code. We all have to deal with it. As I suspected, `ws` is not always the active sheet. Notice that you are looping through a set of sheets with the `For each ws...` statement. I would explore that. You have mix of code, some dealing with the active sheet, some dealing with `ws`. With that kind of cross-over, you can have unexpected results. Maybe spend some time cleaning things up?

Comment: Yeah will likely tackle that tonight.

Comment: phew, you're right, that is some ugly code lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the workbooks that are failing actually have multiple sheets. Note the `For Each ws In wB.Sheets` statement at the top of the code. That loop completes well down near the bottom of the code. If there are multiple sheets, `ws` will most definitely not always be pointing at the active worksheet.

If you always want to work only with the active sheet, remove the loop completely and change these lines in your code:

```
DataLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
SheetLastRow = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
.
.
.
ws.SaveAs sPath & NameOfWorkbook & ".csv", xlCSV
```

To

```
DataLastRow = Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
SheetLastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
.
.
.
SaveAs sPath & NameOfWorkbook & ".csv", xlCSV
```

Comment: Will check this out as well, def remove loop.  Note: Double checked and there is only one sheet in the files that this is happening with.

Comment: This deleted everything including Header.  Its almost as if its applying the delete from the empty file that the code lives in even though the working file is open and changes are applied as the script runs.  All changes affect the script properly except the delete.  Also added updated code.  Loop is still in there but will remove after testing thoroughly.  Any other ideas are appreciated.  Thanks to everyone for looking.

Comment: When dealing with multiple workbooks and worksheets, it is usually best to be very explicit about what are dealing with. You have a lot of code that needs to be updated, but my suggestion is to assign the opened workbook and subsequent worksheets to variables and reference those instead of depending on Active references. Once you've ruled out Excel's guessing at what you're trying to do, it makes it easier to diagnose problems.